# En NavigationView como controlar la pila de fragment cargados cuando pulso atrás

Tags: android-fragment, navigationview, onbackpressed

Disculpad que no pongo código porque aun no tengo nada, pero mi idea es la siguiente:

Quiero hacer un NavigationView implementado en el MainActivity y la duda que me surge es si yo por ejemplo tengo estos fragment:

- Home (página principal donde ver en un RecyclerView una lista de
  películas)
- Crear (introduzco datos de una peli nueva y guardo en API. Tra ello
  redirecciono a Ver)
- Editar (desde Home selecciono del RV una película y cargo los datos
  para editarla, desde aquí guardo su edición y redirecciono al
  fragment Ver)
- Ver (Aquí llegamos al pulsar desde Home, una peli en el RV o redireccionados desde Crear o editar)

Si yo desde Editar, guardo la edición de la peli, y muestro sus nuevos detalles en Ver, lo que no quiero es que al pulsar Atrás (botón físico del dispositivo), me vuelva a Editar, sino que quiero que vuelva a Home. Así evito que recargue datos anteriores a la edición. Lo mismo quiero con Crear.

Se que existe onBackPressed en el mainActivity, pero en los fragment no se como implementarlo.
¿Puedo saber en todo momento de que fragment vengo y así en el onStop del fragment que abandono puedo poner algún método que evite recargar el fragment anterior si no quiero?

Comment: Te recomendaría que implementes el patrón conocido como Singe Activity, es decir, tu App tendrá una sola actividad principal y luego usas el patrón de navegación para moverte entre fragmentos y si necesitas pasar datos de una parte a otra  lo puedes hacer fácilmente, porque Navigation permite pasar argumentos sin demasiadas complicaciones. Olvídate de onBackPressed y demás historias, no creo que lo necesites, más bien arrojará confusión a tu código, desaprovechando las ventajas que ofrece el Componente de Navegación. Échale un vistazo a la documentación y haz pruebas, es la mejor forma ...

Comment: ... de aprender cómo funciona (es más simple de lo que crees) y si tienes algún problema nos dices, mostrando en concreto el problema. [Este debe ser tu punto de partida](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started?hl=es-419). Una vez entendido eso, haz un intento con una sola Activity y tus primeros dos fragmentos, luego incorpora tus otros fragmentos y vuelve siempre a tu única Activity. La forma de pasar contenido entre un fragmento y otro dependerá de tu App, y eso debe ser explicado con claridad en una eventual pregunta aquí.

Comment: Si esto mismo lo he mirado pero aqui la pregunta: ¿Si enlazo Ver con Editar al pulsar atrás debe ir a ese Fragment? Es lo que no logro entender de esta navegación aún.
Vamos lo que quiero evitar es el típico error de por ejemplo estoy logado y me deslogo, y si pulso atrás vuelvo a la actividad que ya no debería ver (por supuesto a parte de validar luego que estes logado etc)

Comment: Por ejemplo en esta transición ... desde detalles solo puedo ir a home o a editar?
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_detalles"
        android:name=".VerDetalles"
        android:label="@string/menu_detalles">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_detalles_to_nav_home"
            app:destination="@id/nav_home" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_detalles_to_nav_Editar"
            app:destination="@id/nav_editar" />
    </fragment>

Comment: Si tú usas el patrón Single Activity, siempre que se pulse en el botón de retroceso, el fragmento irá a Home. Esto es lo más recomendable y lo más simple. Aparte de eso, si desde algún lugar (un fragmento cualquiera), tú quieres ir a otro fragmento (por ejemplo al pulsar en un botón), tú puedes navegar a ese otro fragmento de forma programática (desde el onClick del botón que haya sido pulsado).

Comment: Voy a investigarlo a ver si soy capaz. Gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: De hecho, en opciones de Menú por ejemplo, o en items de un RecyclerView o en cualquier parte, tú puedes también poner como valor una destinación y cuando se pulsa en ese elemento, tú puedes navegar de forma programática a ese destino. Es decir, NO se navega a destinos solamente cuando se pulsa en el botón de retroceso, sino que tú puedes invocar el NavController también por código y pasarle un destino. Esto, combinado con que puedes pasar argumentos, es una de las posibilidades más poderosas del Componente de Navegación.

Comment: Este es un ejemplo en el `ViewHolder` de un RecyclerView que puede tener cientos de elementos: `v.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("bookId", mItem.getId());
                Navigation.findNavController(v1).navigate(R.id.nav_book, bundle);
            });` Si observas, al hacer click en cualquiera de los elementos de ese RV estoy navegando al destino `nav_book` y le paso un `Bundle` con un dato que me interesa, que es el ID del libro y con eso presento contenido en ese destino. Aquí se navega de forma programática.

Comment: Si esto mismo estaba usándolo yo para ir de un fragment a otro directamente con listener en los onclick de ImagenView o Button. 
Me sigue sin quedar claro como automáticamente al pulsar en el botón físico del dispositivo, me manda a la home. 
He estado buscando por Single Activity y salvo lo que me has puesto por aqui, no encuentro nada relacionado con NavController.

Comment: [Revisa la documentación de Android al respecto](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui?hl=es-419). En un contexto de Single Activity los fragmentos de nivel inferior mostrarán por defecto la flecha hacia atrás en la parte superior izquierda y al pulsar sobre ella se volvería al home. Y en tu actividad única tendrías que controlar con `onSupportNavigateUp()`

Comment: Te agradezco muchísimo la ayuda que me estás mostrando, pero creo que no me llegué a explicar bien o no te termino de entender.
Lo que necesito no es el icono de menú de la propia navigatión. Ahi efectivamente lo puedo controlar como bien dice la documentación, incluyendo los fragment en en el mobile_navigation. 
Mi duda es en relación al botón físico que tienen todos los teléfonos para ir atrás, es decir, no en la propia aplicación, sino el propio botón de atrás del terminal. 
Supongo que no me estoy enterando yo por mucho que lo intentas jaja pero estoy un poco obcecado. Gracias,un saludo

Comment: El botón físico de retroceder funcionaría igual, cuando le des a ese botón, iría al Home.